# Are we going to have sponsored links like StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

I see that StackOverflow has sponsored links, for example, see the [visual studio tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2010).

I'm unable to find info about how to sponsor a link on SO.

Will the GIS stackexchange site have sponsored links?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but probably not for some time. Programs like this will be implemented if it makes sense for the community.