# Do sponsored tags make sense for GIS.se?

Tags: discussion

When I asked about sponsored <del>links</del> tags  on GIS.se, Robert Cartaino [said](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116/are-we-going-to-have-sponsored-links-like-stackoverflow/119#119):

> It is possible, but probably not for
>   some time. Programs like this will be
>   implemented if it makes sense for the
>   community.

So I guess we need to decide if it makes sense for GIS.se.  Should we vote on it here?

Has anyone analyzed the impact of sponsored <del>links</del> tags on stackoverflow with respect to site growth?

Once a corporation sponsors a <del>link</del> tag, I suspect they also encourage (or at least allow) their technical staff to answer questions.

**Edit**

On Stackoverflow, some tags are "sponsored", see this example for the [windows-phone-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7) tag.

Comment: hmmm, 6 views in 4 days, I'll take that as a "no".

Comment: I'm not sure precisely what a "sponsored link" entails.  Perhaps you could more fully describe what you had in mind, Kirk?